# Checking for NULL values in SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm using this query to get news articles by tags.

```
SELECT N.*
FROM News N
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM STRING_SPLIT(N.Tags, ',') s1 JOIN
                   STRING_SPLIT('tag1,tag2,tag3', ',') s2
                   ON s1.value = s2.value
             );
```

I'm wondering if there is any possibility to return all news articles if no tags were defined in query. For example:

```
SELECT N.*
FROM News N
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM STRING_SPLIT(N.Tags, ',') s1 JOIN
                   STRING_SPLIT(NULL, ',') s2
                   ON s1.value = s2.value
             );
```

Comment: Is the delimited value being passed to `s2` *actually* a parameter? Otherwise, in truth, the above doesn't really make a lot of sense.

Comment: @Larnu I'm getting value for s2 from `@Request('tag')`.

Comment: What does `@Request('tag')` mean? You can't call methods on a variable or parameter

Comment: @MartinSmith In setup I'm working with, I can use URL params like `http://localhost/list?tag=tag1,tag2`. The whole things is about how to get all values if I just request `http://localhost/list` without any URL parameters.

Comment: By the way you should pass in a Table valued Parameter, instead of splitting strings

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we *assume* that the value being passed to `s2` is a parameter, as the above doesn't make a lot of sense otherwise, you could use an `OR`. I also suggest adding `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` as the query plan for the `NULL` and non-`NULL` queries will likely be different, thus this stops poor query caching:

```sql
SELECT N.* --Replace with Columns
FROM dbo.News N
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM STRING_SPLIT(N.Tags, ',') s1 
                   JOIN STRING_SPLIT(@Param, ',') s2 ON s1.value = s2.value)
    OR @Param IS NULL
OPTION (RECOMPILE);
```

You can read more on why `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` is a good choice in [Revisiting catch-all queries](https://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2018/03/13/revisiting-catch-all-queries/) and [An Updated Kitchen Sink Example](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-updated-kitchen-sink-example).

Answer (score 2):

A simple method is a second check:

```
SELECT N.*
FROM News N
WHERE @tag_list IS NULL OR
      EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM STRING_SPLIT(N.Tags, ',') s1 JOIN
                   STRING_SPLIT(@tag_list, ',') s2
                   ON s1.value = s2.value
             );
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry for confusion around my query. I hope you will understand what I tried to achieve with this working example:

```
SELECT N.*
FROM News N
      WHERE CONCAT(',', N.Tags, ',') LIKE ISNULL('%@Request("tags")%', '') OR
      EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM STRING_SPLIT(N.Tags, ',') s1 JOIN STRING_SPLIT('@Request("tags")', ',') s2 ON s1.value = s2.value)
OPTION (RECOMPILE);
```

Comment: Is this an answer, or an extension on the attempt you made? If this is an answer, I don't recommend it; your first clause isn't SARGable so would be awful for performance.

Comment: It's the answer. But I will look into problem with first caluse.

Comment: Though I am "self promoting", I suggest having a look at my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68177446/2029983) again. That is the syntax you want to go with